# How to run Prisma migration after PostgreSQL service is started

Tags: docker

I'm currently working on a project using NestJS, Prisma and PostgreSQL in a dockerized environment. I have a service for `api_server` and another one for running `postgres`. I want to run migration before the `api_server` starts. So I tried to use this in the Dockerfile of `api_server`

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine
# Set user and working directory
# Working directory needs to be under /home/node
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/server
COPY package.json .
# Install node dependencies
RUN yarn
COPY . ./
RUN yarn generate
# the original migration command is kept on the package.json
RUN yarn migrate
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

But it seems that during the build step of images, none of the services is up. So it throws an error because it can not establish a database connection. What could be a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, service is not up. Best Way for me is add a healthcheck.

Take a look at [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/41854997#41854997)